# Attempting to label bars in chart, but produces text multiple times

Tags: java, swing, bar-chart

I'm creating a program that request the sales from users for a month, and executing the sales to bar chart. The program runs and produces the bars correctly; however The text is not executing correctly. I'm attempting to place title "Monthly Sales" as title of chart, label the bars with the sales associate name, and label the value of the bars on the left side of the chart. Any suggestions will be helpful. It is producing "Monthly Sales" repeatedly all over the chart.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BarGraph extends JPanel
{
 //set variables for graph
     JLabel jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3, jLabel4, jLabel5;

    private Map<Color, Integer> bars =
           new LinkedHashMap <>();


    //execute bars and color
    public void addBar(Color color, int value)

   {
      bars.put(color, value);
      repaint();

   }

        //create paint components of chaart
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)

   {


       Dimension d = getSize();
    int clientWidth = d.width;
    int clientHeight = d.height;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for (Integer value : bars.values())
      {
         max = Math.max(max, value);
      }
           jLabel1 = new JLabel("Sales For Month", JLabel.CENTER);
        // We can position of the text, relative to the icon:
        jLabel1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);

        jLabel2 = new JLabel("PAM");
                jLabel3 = new JLabel("Leo");
                jLabel4 = new JLabel("Kim");
        jLabel5 = new JLabel("BOB"); // Label of Icon Only
        // Add labels to the Panel
        add(jLabel1);




      //paint bar
      int width = (getWidth() / bars.size()) - 2;
      int x = 1;
      for (Color color : bars.keySet())
      {
         int value = bars.get(color);
         int height = (int)
                 ((getHeight() -5) * ((double)value /max));
         g.setColor(color);
         g.fillRect(x, getHeight() - height, width, height);
         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.drawRect(x, getHeight() - height, width, height);
         x += (width + 2);       
      }




   }
   //set bar size
   public Dimension getPreferredSize()
   {
      return new Dimension(bars.size() * 10 + 2, 50);
   }

  //create main to generate charte
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Friendly Hal's Auto");
      BarGraph graph = new BarGraph();
      //set frame size
      frame.setSize(350, 300);
      //create variable for user input
      int carsSold1;
      int carsSold2;
      int carsSold3;
      int carsSold4;  

      //request user input

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many cars did Pam sell for the month?");
      carsSold1 = input.nextInt();        
      System.out.println("How many cars did Leo sell for the month?");
      carsSold2 = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("How many cars did Kim sell for the month?");
      carsSold3 = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("How many cars did Bob sell for the month?");
      carsSold4 = input.nextInt();

      //color bar to user choice
     graph.addBar (Color.red, carsSold1);
     graph.addBar (Color.green, carsSold2);
     graph.addBar(Color.blue, carsSold3);
     graph.addBar(Color.yellow, carsSold4);
     frame.getContentPane().add(graph);

     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);


  }
```

Comment: You don't create want to components inside of the paintComponent method. That's a bit on the crazy side since you don't control when or if that method gets called, and you're slowing down a method that must be blindingly fast. Just do painting in there and **nothing** else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is, you've broken the paint chain...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    // Your problem is right here...

    Dimension d = getSize();
```

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to clear the `Graphics` context (with the components background color) ready for painting...

Add `super.paintComponent(g);` as the first call to your `paintComponent` method, before you do any custom painting

A `Graphics` context is a shared resources, all components painted within a given paint cycle will share the same `Graphics` context and on some systems, it will be the same for all paint cycles, so you need to make sure that it is cleared before you use it...

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

**Updated**

As point out by @HovercraftFullOfEels, you are creating UI elements within a `paintComponent`, painting should paint the current state of the UI, and should NOT make ANY modifications to it.  Painting is done when the repaint manager thinks it should be done, so your `paintComponent` may be called a number of times, depending on what you are doing.

Modifying the state of the UI from within the `paintComponent` can set up an infinite loop of repaint requests which will eventually consume your CPU cycles and make your PC unusable...

May also want to take a read through [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and ensure that your UI is created and modified only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

You should also not be mixing UI and console based approaches, they don't mix well together...

Comment: He's also creating and placing JLabels in that method.

Comment: Do I create a new method for the Labels only